# How to store integer value into an NSMutableArray in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have `NSMutableArray` having values 10,15,26,28. I want to store them into another array as an integer form how do i store them.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

here how to add

```
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
```

you can get the integer value like

```
//assuming array has nsnumber/nsstring objects.

[[array objectAtIndex:index] intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
int yourInt = 5;
[myMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourInt]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store C types in a NSMutableArray, you can only store objects.
Create NSNumber's from your int values with `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10];`...

You can then get the int value back with `[aNSNumberObject intValue];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store integers in an array it has to be a C array:

```
#define C_ARRAY_MAX_SIZE 10
int cTab[C_ARRAY_MAX_SIZE];
int i=0;

for (NSNumber* n in yourMutableArray) {


 cTab[i] = [n intValue];
    i++;

}
```